How can I draw a line of a specific candle in a specific time of a specific character?
I want to draw a line of a specific candle in a specific time (9:30) of a specific character (Open price) as a step line; when next candle at 9:30 opens, the line takes new value of new candle. I tried to do it myself but it does not look like I would like it to look like.
So I input Data as open, probably time date is a problem; I put it as session, but input.time does not seeem to work; at least with my skills.
I extract the data to the value (Data * 1) because it's constant line of opening price and plot it.
Could ANYONE change it to work the way it should work; like constant, horizontal line from 9:30 to next 9:30 candle, then starting from thew new 9:30 candle (step line?)
//@version=5
indicator("ONE LINE", overlay=true)

show1 = input(true, "LINE ONE", inline="LINE ONE")
color1 = input(#ff0000, "", inline="LINE ONE")


LineOneData = input.source(open, title="LINE ONE")
LineOneDate = input.session("0930-0931")
LineOneValue = LineOneData * 1

plot(show1 ? LineOneValue : na, color=color1, linewidth=4, title="LINE ONE")




Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You must reassign the var LineOneValue
//@version=5
indicator("ONE LINE", overlay=true)

show1 = input(true, "LINE ONE", inline="LINE ONE")
color1 = input(#ff0000, "", inline="LINE ONE")


LineOneData = input.source(open, title="LINE ONE")
LineOneDate = input.session("0930-0931")

issession = not na(time(timeframe.period,LineOneDate))
var LineOneValue = 0.0
LineOneValue := issession ? LineOneData * 1 : LineOneValue

plot(show1 ? LineOneValue : na, color=color1, linewidth=4, title="LINE ONE")



with not na and time has a bool var
issession = not na(time(timeframe.period,LineOneDate))

something like that
//@version=5
indicator("ONE LINE", overlay=true)

show1 = input(true, "LINE ONE", inline="LINE ONE")
color1 = input(#ff0000, "", inline="LINE ONE")


LineOneData = input.source(open, title="LINE ONE")
LineOneDate = input.session("0930-0931")

issession = not na(time(timeframe.period,LineOneDate))
LineOneValue = issession ? LineOneData * 1 : na

plot(show1 ? LineOneValue : na, color=color1, linewidth=4, title="LINE ONE")



Hi, Thank You very much for your time. We are almost there;

https://ibb.co/J5FXBMB

Your line on the picture I uploaded is red, and I want it to be like the blue one; like a pivot, horizontal line.

If You could adjust the code a little bit, I would be very grateful.

And if I may have a request; the Value of line needs to be defined  (like it is now) so I can use it later on in my next calculations, that part I can do alone; just need that line;-D    Thank You in advance.
